# Can my system be infected with the Trojan known as commondatastorage?

Tags: malware

On Facebook, a friend sent a post with many names including mine. There was a video and I clicked. It opened a page with nothing. The URL started with commondatastorage.google.apis and more. Nothing showed up on this page.  But, am I stuck with a virus?

I use Ubuntu as an operating system on a system76 computer. That's the extent of my knowledge right now on my computer. I installed ClamTK from my Ubuntu software.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how this is related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is consistent with reports of a Trojan sometimes called commondatastorage that is being distributed through Facebook. However, this virus only affects Windows. If you are using Ubuntu, you should be safe.